# composition over inheritance, even is it a Is-a relationship

Tags: python

I try to use composition even the relationship is: is-a.

So I have a Animal class and I have a Zebra class:

```
class Name:
    pass


class Age:
    pass

class Zebra():
    pass


class Animal:

    def __init__(self, name_animal, age_animal) -> None:
        self.name_animal = name_animal
        self.age_animal = age_animal
        self.name = Name()
        self.age = Age()
        self.zebra = Zebra()

    def __repr__(self):
              return "My name is {} and I am {} years old".format((self.name_animal), (self.age_animal))


zebra1 = Zebra('Zebra', 37)
print(zebra1)
```

but then of course it fails because Zebra has no arguments.

So is it possible to use the repr method also for Zebra without inheritcance but with compostion?

Because I get now this error:

```
TypeError: Zebra() takes no arguments
```

Comment: So I just try to experiment with python.

Comment: Your composition is going the wrong way. If you really *want* to emulate inheritance with a member field, then you want `Zebra` to have an `Animal`, not the other way around. Also, you're probably looking for `__str__`. `__repr__` is supposed to produce either a valid Python expression or a descriptor in angled brackets, whereas `__str__` is intended to produce user-friendly strings of text.

Comment: An animal wouldn't have a `zebra` attribute; it would have a `kind` attribute that would have some value that tags a particular instance of `Animal` as a zebra, or a horse, or whatever other kind of animal your class can represent. With inheritance, the class itself serves as the tag.

Comment: oke, but what is then the soluiton? Because it is better never use inheritance. But how to re use name of animal also in Zebra? Without inheritance?

Comment: *”it is better never use inheritance”* — What? Using inheritance is perfectly fine and has its perfectly fine uses. Use inheritance where it makes sense (here for example), and use composition where inheritance makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe you're confusing composition with the strategy pattern. It's kind of a mix of inheritance and composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend to use composition in this case. This is a use-case for inheritance. But academic questions also deserve an answer.

Add a constructor to `Zebra` that initializes and stores an `Animal` instance and delegate `__repr__`:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name_animal, age_animal) -> None:
        self.name_animal = name_animal
        self.age_animal = age_animal

    def __repr__(self):
        return "My name is {} and I am {} years old".format((self.name_animal), (self.age_animal))

class Zebra():
    def __init__(self, name_animal, age_animal) -> None:
        self.animal = Animal(name_animal, age_animal)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.animal.__repr__()

zebra1 = Zebra('Zebra', 37)
print(zebra1)
```